# Performance and optimisation while updating a property value in Update() with unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm very new to Unity (im coming from the web industry) and I'm digging into Physics and unity lifecycle.

I'm wondering about performance and optimisation issue on a very basic topic which is updating a value at runtime.

Considering this snippet :

```
private void Update()
  {
    // updating movement value when user press WASD or arrow keys
    _movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), 0);
  }

private void FixedUpdate()
  {
    Move(_movement, _speed);
  }

public void Move(Vector3 movement, float speed)
  {
    _rb.MovePosition(transform.position + (movement * speed * Time.deltaTime));
  }
```

As I understand it, Unity will update 60 times per second my `_movement` property, even though it hasnt changed. Isn't that a lack of optimisation? Is there a better way or is it totally fine? The same question would apply with `If (Input.GetKeyDown( ... ) )` as I understand that 60 times per second it will check if the condition is true or not.

Is there some kind of Event system that could trigger the `_movement` or `GetKeyDown` without checking it constantly? If yes, is it a better practice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polling for input in `Update` is standard.

In this specific case, you could just as well call `Move` in `Update()` and remove `FixedUpdate()` if you wanted, as `_rb.MovePosition` does  interpolated movement regardless of the context it's called in:

```
private void Update()
{
    // updating movement value when user press WASD or arrow keys
    _movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), 0);

    bool shouldMove = Mathf.Abs(_movement.x) > Mathf.Epsilon 
            || Mathf.Abs(_movement.y) > Mathf.Epsilon; 

    if (shouldMove) Move(_movement, _speed); 
}

public void Move(Vector3 movement, float speed)
{
    _rb.MovePosition(transform.position + (movement * speed * Time.deltaTime));
}
```

The only reason you need to call something in `FixedUpdate` is if you have a reason for it to be called multiple times between renderings or updates to Input. In the specific case in the question, there is no such reason:

Consider the case where you call `Move` in `Update`. In a particularly laggy frame where the input * speed is `abc` and `deltaTime` is `0.2`:

```
_rb.MovePosition(transform.position + abc * 0.2);
// transform.position is updated = starting position + abc * 0.2
```

And in the case where you call `Move` in `FixedUpdate` with that same laggy frame, where input * speed would stil be `abc` and `fixedDeltaTime` (or `deltaTime`) is `0.05`:

```
_rb.MovePosition(transform.position + abc * 0.05);
// transform.position is updated = starting position + abc * 0.05
_rb.MovePosition(transform.position + abc * 0.05);
// transform.position is updated = starting position + abc * 0.1
_rb.MovePosition(transform.position + abc * 0.05);
// transform.position is updated = starting position + abc * 0.15
_rb.MovePosition(transform.position + abc * 0.05);
// transform.position is updated = starting position + abc * 0.2
```

Because the direction/magnitude that the `_rb` was being moved did not change between physics calculations, it is equivalent to putting it in `Update` and having it be called only once.

A counterexample where you would want to call `Move` in `FixedUpdate` would be a where a hazard causes controls to invert (i.e., some flag gets set) if `_rb` collides with it. Then, you would maybe want to check for that inversion flag having been set on each physics update.

Comment: I've edited a bit my script adding a condition to execute the `MovePosition` only if needed. 
`float horizontalMovement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");` `float verticalMovement = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");` `shouldMove = Mathf.Abs(horizontalMovement) > Mathf.Epsilon || Mathf.Abs(verticalMovement) > Mathf.Epsilon;` `if (shouldMove) _rb.MovePosition(transform.position + (abc * Time.deltaTime));`
So the idea here is to perform the movement on the rigidbody only if `shouldMove` is true, that is to say only if `Horizontal` and/or `Vertical` keys are pressed. What do you think? thanks

Comment: @GreatHawkeye yeah, that probably saves more than it costs. Not a bad improvement.  I'll include that in my answer.